# Exception: cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=1 (# cursors opened by this proc=1)

Tags: android

I have the typical crash for cursor allocation however this time I saw that it says that I have 1 open cursor which I'm guessing is the one that it crashed at?

`Fatal Exception: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=1 (# cursors opened by this proc=1)`

All the answers I have found in StackOverflow point at it being an issue with leaving cursors open, but the error says there is only 1 cursor open. Am I misreading that?

This is my typical SQL query code in case anyone is curious:

```
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = db.query(....);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            //do stuff
        }
    } finally {
        if (c != null) c.close();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have several methods that access the db or is this your only method?